# How to keep Session Alive beyond its MaxInactive interval

Tags: jsf, session, user-inactivity

I am Switching between **two different Dynamic web application** through Links.But if i am working on one application for long time then others application session expires and i got redirected to login page, Is there any method to keep session alive beyond **maxInactive** time interval while i am working on other application page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options-

1. If both applications requires single sign on feature (like we login to gmail, then all google services are accessible), you can use tomcat clustering and share session accross cluster. Both your apps will be part of the cluster.
2. A simple work aroud would be to set a heartbeat ajax request in each application. Use JavaScript's timeout function and send ajax request to servlet after a fix interval.

Comment: Can you give some example of Heartbeat ajax request or some helpful link

Answer (score 0):

You can anyway update `MaxInactiveInterval` of server at runtime, there is this method `setMaxInactiveInterval` available for `HTTPsession` class object.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This method can change inactive interval But cant stop session to get expire while working on page of other application

Comment: yes, certainly, actually couldn't find anything to stop session expiration, I thought it might be helpful for you, I'll surely post answer for stoping expiration of session if I'll get one.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one option here that is to manage your own **Session Pool**. You can save the session object in `ArrayList<HttpSession>` whenever you create new session. And send that session id to your another application. When you return to previous app, you send back session id. And if you find session dead then find that session in your **Session Pool** by session id and create new session. In new session set attributes of the previous session object.

Hope this might be useful.

Comment: Any Exaple or helpfull link..??